# Getting 'gpg' error when running sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt

When I run this command {sudo apt-get update} it cant be executed and the response is:

```
E: Type 'gpg' is not known on line 27 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: "xenial" is Ubuntu 16.04 which is out of support.

Comment: The question does not include Line 27 of the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list, so you are asking us to speculate about the problem. The usual culprit is a user typo. You must edit that line of that file to fix the typo. However, since Ubuntu 16.04 (non-ESM) is no longer receiving security patches, it shouldn't be on any network anyway. So the question seems moot.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title, since it seemed greatly exaggerated.